# Reverse for 'Article' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['this_is_article_number/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

```
**my post/urls.py**
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views
   
  urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
         path('<int:post_id>/details', 
                views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='Article'),
        ]
    
    
**post/models.py**

from django.db import models
from froala_editor.fields import FroalaField
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
    serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
    title = models.CharField(default='Title of article', 
max_length=500)
    content = FroalaField()
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    popular = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

**post/Views.py**

```
from django import views
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django import views
from .models import Post



class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        context = {
            "posts": posts
        }
        return render(request, "home.html", context=context)
    
    

class ArticleDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, post_id):
        detail = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        context = {
            "detail": detail
        }
        return render(request, "article.html", context=context)
```

**home.html**

```html
    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
        
    <header>
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="hero">
                <div class="hero-left">
                    <h1 class="main-heading">Live Blogger</h1>
                    <p class="main-subheading">Learn to design websites</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More</a>
                </div>
                <div class="hero-right">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/hero-image.png' %}" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="posts-wrapper">
            <h2>Latest Blog Posts</h2>
    
            <div class="blogpost-card">
                <div class="thumbnail-image">
                    {% for post in posts %}
    
                    <a href="{% url 'Article' post.id %}"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
    
                <a href="{% url 'Article' post.id %}">
                    <h3 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
                </a>
                <div class="post-meta">{{ post.post_time}}</div>
    
                <div class="post-body">
                    <p>
                        {{ post.content|safe}}
                    </p>
    
                    <div class="read-more-container">
                        <a href="{% url 'Article' post.id %}" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    
    
        <div class="popular-posts-container">
            <h2>Popular Posts</h2>
    
            <div class="popular-posts">
                <div class="popular-post">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="{% url 'Article' post.id %}"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="{% url 'Article' post.id %}">
                            <h3 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

please help me i tried to solve this problem by watching many videos on youtube and tried watching more wustion on stachowerflow but now i am really stuck please try to help me .
in html

1. i tried using pk=post.pk it didn't wrok
2. i tried using post.pk it didn't work
3. i tried using pk=post.id it didn't wrok
4. i tried using post.id it didn't work

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes Sir i solved it

Comment: sir can i run a script on a specific timestamp

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, could you please upvote it or even check it as the answer.

Comment: And if you ask that question, I'll try to solve it.

Comment: So, please make a new question.

Comment: Sir please help me .

Comment: Okey, but please make a new question about it.

Comment: I want to click the run button and the scrpit will run on a specific time that i will give to it

Comment: I want to know whether my answer helped or not. So I can remove it.

Comment: sir it helped a lot but the problem was fixed by adding a if statment in the for loop at the template

Comment: Oh, could you show me that so that I can learn from it. I'm learning Django myself.

Comment: And I realized that you cannot upvote my answer because you don't have enough requtation.

Comment: Yes sir it is like that

Comment: i am sending the code to you but let me know whother can you help me with how to run my code on a specific time

Comment: Did you make a new question in this site? I do not see it. And what do you mean you sent me the code to me?

Comment: No sir i want to learn just that that if i have a code and above it i read a code which will alow the code below it to run on a specific timestamp like if i give it to run on 12:45pm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to import `View`.

Write following code in your `HomeView` in views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        context = {
            "posts": posts
        }
        return render(request, "home.html", context=context)
```

And edit your `{% for post in post_list %}` to `{% for post in posts %}` in your home.html

```
class ArticleDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, post_id):
        detail = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        context = {
            "detail": detail
        }
        return render(request, "detail.html", context=context) # <- I don't know your detail template. Please adjust it by yourself.
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using pk use id

```
class ArticleDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, post_id):
        detail = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        context = {
            "detail": detail
        }
        return render(request, "article.html", context=context)
```

and in your html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    
                    <a href="{% url 'Article' post_id=post.id %}"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="" /></a>
{% endfor %}
```

and in your url

```
path('<int:post_id>/details',Product_detail.as_view(),name='detail'),
```

change acc to this and you are good to go